# No geometry values when importing rasters to PostGIS using raster2pgsql

Tags: postgresql, postgis, rhel, gdal

System software...
RHEL 6.6,   PostgreSQL 9.3.5,   POSTGIS 2.1.5,   GEOS 3.4.2,   GDAL 1.9.2

I'm trying to get my first PostGIS database setup, but am having an issues getting rasters imported to the db with any geometry values.  The database does have the PostGIS and adminpack extension enabled.  Issuing the to following to import the raster (raster.tif) to my database (testdb) with superuser role (benh)...

```
$ raster2pgsql -I -C -F -t 100x100 -s 4326 raster.tif public.raster > raster.sql
$ psql -d testdb -U benh -f raster.sql
```

... which does seem to successfully create the table (EPSG value verified with gdalinfo), but I can't get either QGIS or GeoServer to recognize the table as a raster.  Issuing...

```
$ gdalinfo PG":host=localhost port=5432 dbname=testdb user=benh schema='public' table='raster'"
```

... returns ...

```
...
  SUBDATASET_1253_NAME=PG:host=localhost port=5432 dbname=testdb user=benh  schema=
public table=raster column=rast where='rid = 1253'
  SUBDATASET_1253_DESC=PostGIS Raster at 
public.raster (rast), rid = 1253
  SUBDATASET_1254_NAME=PG:host=localhost port=5432 dbname=testdb user=benh  schema=
public table=raster column=rast where='rid = 1254'
  SUBDATASET_1254_DESC=PostGIS Raster at 
public.raster (rast), rid = 1254
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (   0.0000000,   0.0000000) 
Lower Left  (   0.0000000,   0.0000000) 
Upper Right (   0.0000000,   0.0000000) 
Lower Right (   0.0000000,   0.0000000) 
Center      (   0.0000000,   0.0000000)
```

... which would explain why QGIS and GeoServer are having trouble.  Can somebody offer a suggestion here?  I've already completely uninstalled and reinstalled PostgreSQL, PostGIS, and GDAL without success.  I'm at the bottom of my shallow bag of tricks so any tips would be great.  Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. First of all, have you checked from within Postgres/Postgis that the rasters have loaded properly, something from [ST_SummaryStats](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/RT_ST_SummaryStats.html) or [ST_BandMetaData](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/RT_ST_BandMetaData.html).

Comment: Running each of those indicates that a raster exists, but that all values have a nodata value (-9999).  Is it possible that I haven't enabled POSTGIS_ENABLE_OUTDB_RASTERS and POSTGIS_GDAL_ENABLED_DRIVERS properly?  I've got each set to 1 and True, respectively in /etc/profile.